# Sorting words runs perfectly locally but gives runtime error online

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

My word sort program gets compiled and runs perfectly on my computer but gives runtime error when submitted online. Locally it takes input and provides correct output. I'm unable to understand what is causing this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_word(char word[100][10],int n);

int main(){

    int i,n;
    char word[100][10];
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",word[i]);
        }
    sort_word(word,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n",word[i]);
        }
return 0;
}

void sort_word(char word[100][10], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    char *tmp,s;
    tmp=&s;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        if(strcmp(word[j],word[j+1])>0){
        strcpy(tmp,word[j]);
        strcpy(word[j],word[j+1]);
        strcpy(word[j+1],tmp);
        }
     }
      }
}
```

Comment: I am not facing any issue here... Check the link...  http://codepad.org/CJCSa7Mi

Comment: may be you enters a string of length 10 or greater.

Comment: @someone I don't know but that programming site is still giving me this problem.

Comment: the test cases have all strings less than 10 characters.

Comment: @MayankLal... Where you are running this code???

Comment: @someone Are you asking on my pc or online? PC - In terminal, Online - In NPTEL site.

Comment: Show us the test cases.

Comment: I suggest replacing `%s` with `%10s` to avoid buffer overflows in `scanf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *tmp,s;
tmp=&s;
```

This is wrong for what you are trying to achieve.

`tmp` will be pointing to an array of only 1 character (or simply, to a character).
What you want is a temporary buffer of size `10` (which seems to be the max size you have chosen for your words)

You can simply declare it as a single dimension array : `char tmp[10]`